# C++ template convert function

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose the following types:

```
enum class MyEnum1 {};
enum class MyEnum2 {};
typedef struct MyStruct1 {};
typedef struct MyStruct2 {};
```

and the following (stupid) conversions:

```
MyEnum1 convert_to_MyEnum2(MyEnum2 e) { return MyEnum1(); }
MyEnum2 convert_to_MyEnum1(MyEnum1 e) { return MyEnum2(); }
MyStruct1 convert_to_MyStruct1(MyStruct2 s) { return MyStruct1(); }
MyStruct2 convert_to_MyStruct2(MyStruct1 s) { return MyStruct2(); }
```

I want to have a single convert function that takes a single type and converts it to another.

Now, since the functions always accept a single different type and are not only different by the return type, I can obviously change all the `convert_to_*` into a `convert` and overload this function with all the possibilities I have.

But, I don't like the idea of having user write something like:

```
auto e1 = convert(e2);
Foo(convert(e1));
```

I want the code to be readable so I was thinking of having something like:

```
//make all "convert" overloads private and only expose this function
template<typename To, typename From>
To convert_to(From from)
{
    return convert(from); 
}
```

this way the code will be:

```
auto e1 = convert_to<MyEnum1>(e2);
Foo(convert_to<MyEnum2>(e1));
```

1- Is it possible to avoid the `convert` overload but still use some sort of single entry point \ single function name to achieve what I want? (i.e find some usage to existing `convert_to_x`)

2- I understand this is more code-review related but what is the recommended way (if such exist) to this issue?

Comment: what is `Foo` ?

Comment: btw if it is C++ there is no need for the `typedef` in front of `struct`

Comment: if `Foo` expects a `MyEnum2` but has no ctr taking a `MyEnum1` you could write [converting constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) then the user would not have to type anything extra for the conversion to take place

Comment: I don't want to allow implicit casts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a conversion function covering multiple types with a single name can be implemented with [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

```
enum class MyEnum1 {};
enum class MyEnum2 {};
struct MyStruct1 {};
struct MyStruct2 {};

// Unimplemented general fall-back case.
// Note: there are more civilized ways to issue a compilation error...
template<typename To, typename From>
To convert_to(From from) { return To::unimplemented_conversion; }

template<> MyEnum1 convert_to(MyEnum2 from) { return MyEnum1(); }
template<> MyEnum2 convert_to(MyEnum1 from) { return MyEnum2(); }
template<> MyStruct1 convert_to(MyStruct2 from) { return MyStruct1(); }
template<> MyStruct2 convert_to(MyStruct1 from) { return MyStruct2(); }

int main()
{
    MyEnum2 e2 = convert_to<MyEnum2>(MyEnum1());
    MyEnum1 e1 = convert_to<MyEnum1>(e2);
    // MyStruct1 s1 = convert_to<MyStruct1>(e2);  unimplemented conversion
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ZivS You mean `static_assert(false, ...)` (no `std::`, it's a keyword; `false` because `true` never fails)? Of course not, that would trip compilation even if the general case is not used.

Comment: You're totally right, don't know why I added `std`. And indeed static assert this way will not help. Any way thanks for the answer